# VS2012 crashes after putting ILPanel to WinForm

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I'm trying to get ILNumerics running and I'm following the manual on the ILNumerics page.
Means, I created a WinForm application and installed ILNumerics using NuGet. At the end,
I have the reference to ILNumerics.dll added to my application as well as the additional
folder Bin32 and Bin64 added to my project.

Then I added the three using directives to my Form1.cs and also added ILNumerics.dll to
the Toolbox in order to see the controls.

My WinForm application has the target platform set to x86.

Now, I should be able to add f.e. the ILPanel to my WinForm. If I try to do so, VS2012 crash completely without any messages. This behavious remains the same in case, I also add the OpenTK.dlls to my project (not sure, this is necessary).

I also tried to download the sources and build them and then to add the builded dll to my project. After a while, I was able to add a ILPanel to my WinForm (I've no idea, why this was possible), but then if I go throught with the debugger, the debugger stops working within the constructor of ILOGLControl().

Any ideas, what's wrong?

Regards, Thomas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) for more details.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to instantly crash VS to the desktop without any diagnostic with a poorly programmed control.  It is such a pervasive problem that they named this web site after the it.

Comment: What if you run without the debugger attached ?

Comment: I again added an ILPanel manually to the Application - still not able to open the WF designer - then I see a dialog with the ILPanel inside (starting with Ctrl+F5). If I start with F5 (debugger), I end up in the constructor, described above.

Comment: If I try to add some output to the panel, I see no dialog any more. I activated all exception and get (after several tries this one: A first chance exception of type 'OpenTK.PlatformException' occurred in OpenTK.dll
Additional information: Could not establish connection to the X-Server. Maybe, this is the reason?)